# Core Data Relation: Filter and Sort

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, fetch

In my coredata I have two entities (Profile, Photo). Profile has a toMany relationship (photos) to Photo.

I'm able to access the Photos:

```
// all
let photos = profile.photos?.allObjects

// sorted
let photos = profile.photos?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "ordering", ascending: true)])

// filtered
let photos = profile.photos?.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "type = 'x'"))
```

Is there an easy way to combine filtering and sorting using the relation or do I have to crate a separate `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: Why don't you try to apply a `filtered(using:)` to the result of `sortedArray(using:)` ? But don't forget to cast the result of `sortedArray..` to `NSArray` before calling the `filtered`

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, your question is not related to core data, it is related to sorting and filtering on same array, so please try following code

```
let photos = profile.photos?.allObjects
let result = photos
                .filter { $0.type == "x" }
                .sort { $0.ordering < $1.ordering }
```

As another way, if you don't want to add explicit filter and sorting on result array, then you can create a fetch request, and add predicate with sort  descriptor, so you will get expected result.

Comment: This works for me too. I don't know which is the better solution, so I will choose accepted answer according to votes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Toldy, this works for me:

```
var photos = profile.photos?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "ordering", ascending: true)]) as! [Photo] as NSArray
photos = photos.filtered(using: NSPredicate(format: "type = 'x'")) as NSArray
```